# Cannot open file for writing: Permission denied when trying to save my hosts file edits

Tags: terminal

I am trying to add a line to my `/etc/hosts` file but when I go to save it, I get the error "Cannot open file for writing: Permission denied".

The permissions for the file (`ls -la /etc/hosts`) is as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  289 Apr 22  2021 /etc/hosts
```

I've been searching the internet but still can't find my answer. I am running macOS Ventura.  How can I edit this file?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using?  Also, it tells you it's a permissions issue.  What does `ls -la /etc/hosts` produce?

Comment: @Allan Ventura 13.1

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  289 Apr 22  2021 /etc/hosts` This is what I got!

Comment: That tells you it is readable by root, users in the wheel group, and everyone else.  It is only writeable by root.  So, to edit it, you need to preface your command with `sudo`.  For example, if using the nano editor: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.  Enter your password and you'll be able to edit.

Comment: Oh wow, okay! Thanks so much- I really appreciate it.

Comment: Go ahead and write it up as an answer then reply to this comment.  This way I can up vote it!

Comment: I wrote up the answer!

Comment: Cool.  I edited it a bit to make it a bit more "attractive."  Oh...and welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: You have been extremely helpful. Thank you for the warm welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be a permissions issue.  To edit, the [`sudo`](https://ss64.com/osx/sudo.html) must be used to edit with root permissions:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```